# SQL COUNT with the same attribute

Tags: mysql, count

I got this question and have no idea how to do it

with these tables provided:

```
Webpage (url, title);
User (username, age);
VisitLog(url, username, timestamp);
```

Q: Create a view OftenVisited(url, username) that shows pairs of urls and usernames such that the webpage has been visited more than 25 times by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need the first two tables(Webpage, User) in your query, because you got the data that you need in the third table(VisitLog).
Try following query-

```
SELECT url, username
FROM VisitLog
GROUP BY url, username
HAVING count(*) > 25
```